# Most Pythonic way to plot a vector function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a function `calcField` which, when given a numpy array with two elements representing a position, returns an array representing the electric field at that position. What is the most pythonic way to ask matplotlib to draw a vector field for this function? Currently I have this code working, but it feels against the spirit of numpy and is relatively unreadable.

```
Y, X = np.mgrid[-3:3:100j, -3:3:100j]

vectors = np.array([[field.calcField(r) for r in row] 
                  for row in [zip(a, b) for a, b in zip(X, Y)]])
U = np.array([[vector[0] for vector in row] for row in vectors])
V = np.array([[vector[1] for vector in row] for row in vectors])

plt.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, color=U, linewidth=2, cmap=plt.cm.autumn)
```

Edit: As requested, the code of calcField:

```
import constants
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as l
class Field:
    def __init__(self, charges = []):
       self.charges = charges
    def addCharge(self, charge):
        self.charges = self.charges + [charge]
    def calcField(self, point):
        point = np.array(point)
        return sum([charge.calcField(point) for charge in self.charges])

class PointCharge:
    def __init__(self, q, position):
        self.q = q
        self.position = np.array(position)
    def calcField(self, point):
        return constants.k * self.q * (point - self.position) / l.norm (point - self.position)**3
```

Comment: Try *vectorizing* the function `calcField`. Once you get the hang of that, you'll be able to get rid of all the other for-loops in this code extract.

Comment: To add on what Oliver said, you'd be able to write `U,V = calcField(X,Y)`. Do so only if it is worth the effort, i.e. this code is very slow or you know that you will often use `calcField()` in the future.

Comment: I have gotten into the habit of representing vectors in N-space as length N numpy arrays, so that instead of keeping track of individual components I can deal only with vector operations. For example, the expression for the field of a point charge is just `k*q*(pos1 - pos2)/np.linalg.norm(pos1 - pos2)**3`. Is there a way to keep this readability in the math while "vectorizing" in the sense of operating on many inputs at once?

Comment: May we have a look at `calcField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vectorized form of your code that plots the electric field of a set of point charges using streamlines might look like this:

```
num_charges = 4
charges = np.random.random_integers(-5,5,num_charges)
charges[charges==0] = 5
charges_positions = np.random.random((num_charges, 2))

y,x = np.mgrid[0:1:40j, 0:1:40j]
xdist = x - charges_positions[:,0].reshape(-1,1,1)
ydist = y - charges_positions[:,1].reshape(-1,1,1)

denom = ((xdist**2 + ydist**2)**1.5)
# Ignoring Coulomb's constant here...
Ex = (charges.reshape(-1,1,1) * xdist / denom).sum(axis=0)
Ey = (charges.reshape(-1,1,1) * ydist / denom).sum(axis=0)
```

Which I find more comprehensible than this alternative, which you might find more readable (and that was your question):

```
num_charges = 4
charges = np.random.random_integers(-5,5,(num_charges,1,1))
charges[charges==0] = 5  # only for clarity
positions = np.random.random((2, num_charges,1,1))

y,x = np.mgrid[0:1:40j, 0:1:40j]
M,N = y.shape
xy = np.array([x,y]).reshape(2,1, M,N)
rad_dist = xy - positions
denom = np.linalg.norm(rad_dist, axis=(0))**3

elec_fields = charges * rad_dist / denom
Ex, Ey = elec_fields.sum(axis=1)
```

You could plot either easily. I'll continue with the format from the last code block (you'll need to swap a few indices if you're using the first form):

```
pos_charges = charges > 0
neg_charges = charges < 0
f,(ax,ax1) = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax.plot(positions[0, pos_charges], positions[1, pos_charges], 'ro ')
ax.plot(positions[0, neg_charges], positions[1, neg_charges], 'bo ')
ax.streamplot(x,y, Ex, Ey, color='k')
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
ax.set_title('Electric field')
ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_yticks([])
```

However, at this point I'm not using classes anymore. Sometimes it's worth it to enjoy easier access to vectorization. In the 2nd form of the code, you basically have the result of each `PointCharge.calcField()` in the 2nd axis of `elec_fields`, the first being merely the x and y components of these fields.

[image: electric field distribution]